# After buying a specific product add a user meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**First Question:** I want to add a user meta after buying a specific product. This specific product defines by ID. How can I achieve this?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_checkout_save_user_meta');
    function bbloomer_checkout_save_user_meta( $order_id ) {
       $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
       $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
          if ( $order->get_total() > 100 ) {  
          add_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_checkbox', 'on');
     }
}
```

**Second Question:** How to remove order info for a specific user using specific product ID? after removing that `wc_customer_bought_product()` need show return false.

Comment: One question at the time please (it's the rule on StackOverFlow)… Actually your question can be stuck as "On hold" for "Too broad" reason at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to your first question:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_checkout_save_user_meta');

function bbloomer_checkout_save_user_meta( $order_id ) {
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $item){
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        if ($product_id == 'YOUR PRODUCT ID HERE'){
           add_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'product_'.$product_id, 'Bought on Order ID: '.$order->get_id());
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: `$value['product_id'];` from where is come the $value?

Comment: oops, it should have been $item, not $value

Comment: product_id should have been $product_id. Please check now (tested)